# Delete list of objects based from an array ids using ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an arrays with ids and object lists with same ids contained in arrays, how can I remove objects based from array ids?

array:

```
user_ids: [“id001”, “id004”]
```

object list:

```
{
    {
        “user_id”: “id001”,
        “city”: “Seattle”
    },
    {
        “user_id”: “id002”,
        “city”: “Los Angeles”
    },
    {
        “user_id”: “id003”,
        “city”: “San Francisco”
    },
    {
        “user_id”: “id004”,
        “city”: “San Diego”
    }
}
```

so the result would be:

```
{
    {
        “user_id”: “id002”,
        “city”: “Los Angeles”
    },
    {
        “user_id”: “id003”,
        “city”: “San Francisco”
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that object an array of objects?

Comment: Your example is not syntactically valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Array methods**

***Array.prototype.filter()***

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

> The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

***Array.prototype.includes()***

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

> The includes() method determines whether an array includes a certain element, returning true or false as appropriate.

```js
let user_ids = ["id001", "id004"];
let list = [
    {
        "user_id": "id001",
        "city": "Seattle"
    },
    {
        "user_id": "id002",
        "city": "Los Angeles"
    },
    {
        "user_id": "id003",
        "city": "San Francisco"
    },
    {
        "user_id": "id004",
        "city": "San Diego"
    }
];

console.log(list.filter( o => !(user_ids.includes(o.user_id)) ));
```

Answer (score 0):

If the list of objects is an array, you could do it like so:

```
for (var i = 0;i<object_list.length;i++){
    if (object_list[i]["user_id"] in user_ids){
        object_list.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

If it is an object, it could be done this way:

```
for (var i in object_list){
    if (object_list[i]["user_id"] in user_ids){
        delete object_list[i];
    }
}
```